# sending html link in SMS message in iPhone

Tags: ios4, hyperlink, sms

I want to send SMS from iPhone to another phone with some text and a link. I can send it as text:

```
"Please click http://www.facebook.com to login to Facebook".
```

but I want to send it like it:

```
"Please click <a href="http://www.facebook.com">HERE</a> to login to Facebook".
```

Is this possible? How can I do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SMS doesn't support anything but plain text AFAIK, so what you want to achieve isn't possible using **SMS**. On the other hand, I believe that **MMS** does support HTML, so you may want to try that instead.

Comment: I finded that SMS uses UTF-8 character encoding. But, cam it parse HTML tags?